# Rails tests trying to delete sql views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, testing, view

I'm trying to finish writing unit and integration tests for my app, but when I ran rake test, I see a lot of errors, all of them caused by the system trying to delete a sql view which is read only. Why is it trying to delete the view when the tests are simply to validate data creation and how do I get my tests past this? The application is working perfectly fine, but I can't get the tests to run properly. (all tests were running fine before sql views got added).

This is the error I see:

```
    Finished in 0.779585s, 39.7647 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectNotInPrerequisiteState: ERROR:  cannot delete from view "playabilitysummary"
DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.
HINT:  To enable deleting from the view, provide an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger or an unconditional ON DELETE DO INSTEAD rule.
: DELETE FROM "playabilitysummary"


Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass



  2) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_contactus:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectNotInPrerequisiteState: ERROR:  cannot delete from view "playabilitysummary"
DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.
HINT:  To enable deleting from the view, provide an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger or an unconditional ON DELETE DO INSTEAD rule.
: DELETE FROM "playabilitysummary"
```

PlayabilitySummary model:

```
class PlayabilitySummary < ActiveRecord::Base

self.table_name = 'playabilitysummary'
  after_initialize :readonly!

end
```

Playability Summary migration:

```
class CreatePlayabilitySummaries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
   CREATE VIEW PlayabilitySummary AS
   SELECT date,user_id,speed,firmness,moisture FROM (((SELECT distinct(schedules.date) as date, speed.user_id as user_id, speed.speed as speed FROM schedules 
join
  (SELECT user_id, measure_date as speed_date, avg(speed) as speed FROM greens group by user_id, measure_date order by user_id, measure_date asc) as speed
on schedules.date = speed.speed_date) as avg1
JOIN
  (SELECT user_id as fuser_id, measure_date as firm_date, avg(firmness) as firmness FROM greens group by user_id, measure_date order by user_id, measure_date asc) as firmness
ON avg1.user_id = firmness.fuser_id AND avg1.date = firmness.firm_date) as avg2
JOIN
  (SELECT user_id as muser_id, measure_date as moist_date, avg(moisture) as moisture FROM greens group by user_id, measure_date order by user_id, measure_date asc) as moisture
ON avg2.fuser_id = moisture.muser_id AND avg2.date = moisture.moist_date)
      SQL
    end

def down
  execute 'DROP VIEW PlayabilitySummary'
end

end
```

Sample test (user_controller):

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question after a recent rails/rspec update and thought the following could be useful. 
If you execute arbitrary SQL commands in your migrations (for example creating view or functions) these could be lost when running tests as the test loads from schema.rb.

Changing the [format of the schema type](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps) to :sql allows the entire structure to be dumped to a file, which means the test runner will now pick these up:

```
# config/application.rb
config.active_record.schema_type = :sql
```

hen running `rake db:schema:dump` to generate the necessary `db/structure.sql` will stop your VIEWS and FUNCTIONs being removed between test runs.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by creating a rake db:views task to create the sql views and removing those from the migration. This kept the test db preparation from trying to drop tables that were defined as read_only.

Additionally, db user was granted superuser access. Both of these steps have successfully eliminated the deletion error.

Comment: thank you, here is a post that explains how to do that https://rietta.com/blog/2015/03/30/adding-rake-db-views-for-sql-views-to-a-rails-project/ but I am still getting the same error